# PHP Mongo Aggregate exception: pipeline element 0 is not an object

Tags: php, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I'm trying to get the number of users with the same email address.

I've followed the php documentation for [MongoCollection Aggregate](http://php.net/manual/en/mongocollection.aggregate.php).  I've also compared my query to the others on stackoverflow.  As far as I can tell my pipeline matches the one in the examples.  And yet I get the error:

`exception: pipeline element 0 is not an object`

Which I presume is the `$group` element, which is an object (once converted to the json format mongo uses, isn't it?

```
$pipeline = array(
  array(
    '$group' => array(
      '_id' => array( 'email' => '$email' ),
      'uniqueIds' => array( '$addToSet' => '$_id'  ),
      'count' => array( '$sum' => 1 )
    )
  ),
  array(
    '$match' => array(
      'count' => array( '$gt' => 1 )
    )
  )
);

$options = array(
  'allowDiskUse' => true
);

$results = $mongo->users_collection->aggregate( $pipeline, $options );
```

What have I done wrong?  I've even tried running the query from php.net, I of course expected no results, but it resulted in the same error!?

**EDIT** so turns out it's when I `allowDiskUse`, but if I remove the `$options` from the function I get an error telling me to use it.

Thanks

Comment: You have a typo on this line `'_id' => array( 'email' => '$email', ),` just get rid of the first comma occurrence `(,)` and rewrite code to show `'_id' => array( 'email' => '$email' ),`

Comment: Thanks, doesn't resolve the bug though :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution to this

```
$results = $mongo->command(array(
  'aggregate' => 'users_collection',
  'pipeline' => $pipeline,
  'allowDiskUse' => true
));
```

It seems to me that because php allows two methods of doing this (from [php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/mongocollection.aggregate.php))

```
public array MongoCollection::aggregate ( array $pipeline [, array $options ] )

public array MongoCollection::aggregate ( array $op [, array $op [, array $... ]] )
```

It is seeing my `$options` array as another operation `$op`.  Maybe this is to do with the version of Mongo Module we're using or something along those lines, but changing to `$mongo->command()` works as a workaround.